# Prism Xamarin Forms injectable objects

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm new to Prism and I'm looking for some guidance on the objects available during viewModel instantiation when using Prism (Prism.Forms 6.2.0 Preview 3)  with Xamarin Forms.

I see that INavigationService and IEventAggregator parameters values are supplied by the framework when navigating to a view/viewmodel. See code below for an illustration.

```
 public ViewBViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IEventAggregator ea)
    {
        _ea = ea;
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }
```

The navigationService and ea objects (above) were populated by Prism.

**Question:**
What other objects can be auto-populated in a viewModel instance by the framework (outside of INavigationService and IEventAggregator)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these are the implementations registered for you:

- INavigationService
- IApplicationProvider
- IModuleManager
- IModuleInitializer
- IEventAggregator
- IDependencyService
- IPageDialogService
- ILoggerFacade

See source [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/162594d32db0d32372ce82dee4bb1301bb70510a/Source/Xamarin/Prism.DryIoc.Forms/PrismApplication.cs#L71-L83).

That being said, I'm only familiar with `INavigationService`, `IEventAggregator` and `IPageDialogService`. `ILoggerFacade` looks interesting.

See documentation [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/162594d32db0d32372ce82dee4bb1301bb70510a/Documentation/Xamarin.Forms).

Comment: Thanks for supplying the link to the constructor code and the additional injected items.  I was also familiar with the INavigationService, IEventAggregator and IPageDialogService.   I will do some additional research on these other injected objects and update the post with my answers if I find good info.  I would give you a point, but my level is too low.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve any service/object that you register with the container. Register your objects with the container inside `RegisterTypes()` method of your `App.xaml.cs` in your `PrismApplication`. Then resolve it by injecting in your constructor.

```
// Register
   Container.RegisterType<IYourObject, YourObject>();

// Resolve
   public SomeClass(IYourObject yourObject) 
   {
      _yourObject = yourObject;
   }
```

If you have a platform-specific dependency, then register those services in your app initializers, for example in iOS, your `AppDelegate.cs` will load the Xamarin.Forms application like this,

```
...

LoadApplication(new App(new iOSAppInitializer()));

...
```

The initializer can look like this

```
public class iOSAppInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{
   public void RegisterTypes (IUnityContainer container)
   {
       container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService> ();
   }
}
```

ALSO, you can register third-party plugins as `RegisterInstance` and inject them in your classes as well. For example, say you are using `Acr.UserDialogs` plugin for alert, instead of using the `static` instance everywhere (which will make Unit Testing interesting), you can simply register it to your container as

```
RegisterInstance<IUserDialogs>(UserDialogs.Instance);
```

and inject it where needed.

```
public SomeClass(IUserDialogs userDialogs)
{
   _userDialogs = userDialogs;
}
```

PS: If the third-party plugin does not expose the abstractions, you can wrap a static and use that to register and resolve.